# Docker: Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates

Tags: docker, certificate, tls1.2

I am having a similar problem. Any direction would help.
The "docker-machine -D ssh default" Allows me to login and work the container.

### but it still bugs me as to why do I see this error?

### here is some of the extract

Copying certs to the local machine directory... Copying certs to the remote machine... Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as the Docker daemon port (usually :2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using. Checking connection to Docker... Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'. Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.

Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'. Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100 For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

> $ docker-machine ls

NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

default            virtualbox   Timeout

> $docker-machine -D ssh default

Docker Machine Version:  0.6.0, build e27fb87
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:50515
() Calling .GetVersion
.
.
.

> $docker-machine regenerate-certs -f default

Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not
reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as
the Docker daemon port (usually :2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
$

Comment: You should mark all of that output as code to preserve the formatting. It wasn't clear to me on first read that it was all output from those commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this happened when on a VPN and docker-machine creates VM's on the same subnet as our internal network and then couldn't route to it. The following helped prevent that.

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.90.1/24" MACHINE_NAME
```

Comment: This did not work for me, also tried another cidr block.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem, what solved for me was to turn-off my VPN client.

Comment: This is on my office ntwk and can't turn off VPN

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out that the office firewall didn't have port 2376 open.