# dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout

Tags: macos, docker, docker-toolbox

I am unable to get Docker Toolbox for Mac running.  I had it running a few months ago perfectly.  But now, it keep getting the errors:

```
This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as the Docker daemon port (usually <ip>:2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
```

Second error

```
Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.
```

I've uninstall and reinstalled, and deleted all my containers multiple times, but keep getting the same errors.

Here's what I've done:

1. Remove all "host-only adapters" using VirtualBox | select machine | Settings | Network remove all Host-only Adapters
2. Remove vboxnet0 interface using

   VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0
3. Uninstall Docker Toolbox for Mac
4. Stop Docker app.
5. Delete Applications directory Docker
6. Stop all running virtual machines (machine reboot does this nicely)
7. Stop VirtualBox
8. Delete Applications directory VirtualBox
9. Bounce vboxnet0 interface

   `sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 down && sudo ifconfig vboxnet0`
10. Reboot Mac
11. Install Docker via download at https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/

    docker version

returns

```
Client:
Version:    18.03.0-ce
API version:    1.37
Go version: go1.9.4
Git commit: 0520e24
Built:  Wed Mar 21 23:06:22 2018
OS/Arch:    darwin/amd64
Experimental:   false
Orchestrator:   swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:    Wed Mar 21 23:14:32 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

12. Completely delete the existing "build" machine

    docker-machine rm build
13. Create machine named "build"

    docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 4096 --engine-opt dns=9.0.128.50 --engine-opt dns=9.0.130.50 build

But I still get the same errors as above.

I've read a number of posts related to this, but nothing seems to help. Tried adding --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.90.1/24" to the create as suggested by [Docker: Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224517/docker-error-checking-tls-connection-error-checking-and-or-regenerating-the-ce), but that didn't help.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Does anyone even have suggestions for how to debug this problem? 
Or what kinds of things might cause these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and none of the things listed in the question resolved it.

What helped me move forward was to delete the vm directory, in my case:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.docker/machine/machines/default
docker-machine create default
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

This nuked everything (lost all images), but resolved the network (?) issue.